# I keep getting compile time error, why?

Tags: java

The code is supposed to write a Java program that reads from the standard input a list of positive integers and determines if any of them can be written as the sum of a subset of the other input integers. Hints: Searching for subsets of integers that add up to a certain value is best done recursively. However, avoid generating all subsets. When you search for a subset with sum x, input integers larger than x do not have to be considered. If y≤x is one of the other input integers, the search for subsets summing up to x can be divided into searching among subsets that include y and those that don't.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class jodiejo {

    public static int[] integers = new int[1000];

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;
        integers = new int[1000];

        while (scan.hasNextInt()) {

            integers[n] = scan.nextInt();
            n++;

        }



        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {

            searchSum(integers[i], i);
        }

        System.out.print("NO");

        Arrays.sort(integers, 0, n);
    }

    public static void searchSum(int number, int position) {
        for (int i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (number - integers[i] == 0) {
                System.out.print("YES");
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (number - integers[i] > 0) {
                searchSum(number - integers[i], i);
            } else if (number - integers[i] < 0) {
                return
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the compiler error?

Comment: Is your code always formatted left-justified? Isn't that hard for you to read, because it's certainly hard for us. Consider putting some effort into presenting well-formatted code as it will make it easier for us to put in effort to read it and help you.

Comment: It looks like some one has come from a C background.  `void` methods don't "need" `return`s, but they definitely like to be friends with `;`

Comment: add a semicolon after return 5th line from the last.

Comment: Try using a IDE to write the code like Eclipse or Notepad++. It will tell these type of errors on the spot

Comment: ok ill see how it goes by removing the return

Answer (score 1):

I think the error must be here:

```
else if(number - integers[i] < 0)
{
return //this is the problem
}
}
```

So just put a semi colon `;` after `return` like `return;`

And why are you initializing your `integers` array second time inside the main method:
`integers = new int[1000];`
It is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

You need a semicolon after that last return, i.e:

```
 public static void searchSum(int number, int position) {
        for (int i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (number - integers[i] == 0) {
                System.out.print("YES");
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (number - integers[i] > 0) {
                searchSum(number - integers[i], i);
            } else if (number - integers[i] < 0) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here, you don't have semicolon after `return` statement:

```
else if(number - integers[i] < 0)
{
return  //No Semicolon
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in line:49

instead of `return` , `return;` - missing `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class jodiejo
{

    public static int[] integers = new int[1000];

    public static void main(String args[])
    {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int n = 0;
        integers = new int[1000];

        while (scan.hasNextInt())
        {

            integers[n] = scan.nextInt();
            n++;

        }



        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {

            searchSum(integers[i], i);
        }

        System.out.print("NO");

        Arrays.sort(integers, 0, n);
    }

    public static void searchSum(int number,
                                 int position)
    {
        for (int i = position - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            if (number - integers[i] == 0)
            {
                System.out.print("YES");
                System.exit(0);
            }
            else if (number - integers[i] > 0)
            {
                searchSum(number - integers[i], i);
            }
            else if (number - integers[i] < 0)
            {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```